# Overriding setAdapter in subclass of ListView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to override method setAdapter in a subclass of ListView.
setAdapter is defined as

```
void setAdapter(T adapter);
```

in AdapterView class. AdapterView class is generic class AdapterView

The declaration from above doesn't work for ListView subclass because type variable is not available, but I don't understand how to introduce the type variable into subclass. Any concrete type doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that `AdapterView` uses a generic type argument, but `ListView` and `GridView` specify that the type must be a `ListAdapter`. So you can do this:

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    // ...
}
```

This is because `ListView`'s parent class, `AbsListView`, extends `AdapterView<ListAdapter>`:

```
public abstract class AbsListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> { ... }
```

Which means `T` is a `ListAdapter` everywhere it's used in `ListView`.

Comment: Yea, I should have looked into AbsListView source code. Android documentation is confusing, it says: AbsListView extends AdapterView<T extends Adapter>